# Java native package requirements

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I inherited some C/C++ code that we need to wrap in Java, and this is a contrived example trying to show the issue.

C/C++:

```
void addTwoNumbers(int x, int y) {
  return x + y;
}
```

Wrapper that works:

```
class Wrapper {
  public native int addTwoNumbers(int x, int y);
}
```

Wrapper that throws a Java unsatisfied link error:

```
package com.ourcompany.wrapper

class Wrapper {
  public native int addTwoNumbers(int x, int y);
}
```

We can't update the C/C++ code. We just get some headers and pre-built libraries. Am I missing something? Because it appears unwilling to link the code if there is a package.

Comment: You must define the header files to point to the correct package if I remember correctly

Comment: That's the problem: we just have a binary blob and can't modify the code due to IP issues.

Comment: So don't add a package name to this particular class.

Comment: Both shouldn't work, because every JNI Function has this form `Java_<packageAndClass>_<methodName>`.

Comment: It is not as simple as creating a Java class and using the `native` keyword. Java's way to interface with native code is [Java Native Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) and it requires the native code to have a specific format. You can use it and write a small C or C++ wrapper layer which your Java code calls, and passes calls on to the C++ code. Using [Java Native Access](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) might be simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, why your first example works. I couldn't reproduce it, because every native method has a special name, that consists of the package name, the classname, ... I would advice to write a native wrapper.

```
class Wrapper {
  public native /*static */ int addTwoNumbers(int x, int y);
}
```

as Java code. After that generate a header with either `javah`(Deprecated and removed in newer versions) or `javac -h`.
You will get following prototype:

`JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Wrapper_addTwoNumbers(JNIEnv *,jobject /*or jclass if static */,jint,jint);`

Now you have to implement the function:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Wrapper_addTwoNumbers(JNIEnv *env,jobject obj,jint a,jint b){
  return addTwoNumbers(a,b);
}
```

Another approach would be JNA:

```
public interface API extends Library {
    API INSTANCE = (API) Native.loadLibrary("library", API.class);
    int addTwoNumbers(int a,int b);
}
```

and use it like that:
`API.INSTANCE.addTwoNumbers(3,4);`

Comment: Nice answer! For completeness you could mention SWIG as well. That will generate Java interface classes from C header files but often needs some massaging.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this tip. I never worked with SWIG before.